# How to access HTTP Server that is being run inside of JNI on android?

Tags: android, http, java-native-interface

I have some Rust code that is running a HTTP Server, and I running that code on android using JNI.
Somehow I cannot access the Webserver that is being run on the JNI side, I've tried it using curl in the adb shell.

What I tried already is adding the Internet Permission to the android app, but no luck here either.

Code that is running the JNI function:

```kotlin
init {
    System.loadLibrary("webserver")
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.startButton)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        startClient()
    }

}

external fun startClient()
```

Comment: You did not post any code for an Android app. So how would we know what you are doing?

Comment: That code tells us nothing. Better post the code for startClient().

Comment: `System.loadLibrary("webserver")` For what does your Android app need a library for a webserver? Your Android app would be a client i suppose(d).

Comment: `and I running that code on android using JNI.` You might bettert explain how you start your webserver.

Comment: @blackapps I need to use the JNI because I am using a rust lib that will server as an API to the android app, and potentially other android apps

Comment: Yes. Ok. But i have no idea how you start your webserver on Android and you did not tell why your Android app needs a webserver library. Well ... i asked that before.

Comment: @blackapps Not sure tbh. The library that I am using starts the webserver, and it works great outside of android (when I just run the rust code). But once I try to run it through JNI, I cannot access the server

Comment: So your Android app -that wants to be a client too- is starting the webserver?

Comment: @blackapps Yes, thats what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Then why didn't you tell that on the first line of your post?. Well ok. Did you try to reach your server using a browser from your Android device?

Comment: @blackapps Basically, I tried to reach it using curl in the shell of the phone and it says "Connection Refused"

Comment: My god... try with a browser on your device!